# SQL query to get the data as per the input

Tags: sql, jdbc

Let’s say I am passing the input as input=2021-01-21,CGT for an sql query. CGT will be the common keyword in the database but the dates keep changing. I want the records which contain CGT and all the other dates except the date mentioned in the input parameter.

Don’t answer it as retrieve all the records that contain CGT and filter it out in Excel as the records for the particular date is huge in number. So I want the other dates which are less in count which can be handled.

Example query :-
select records from tablename where var_name=‘input’;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I assume that this is what you want.

```
Given:

|    input    |
--------------- 
2021-01-21,CGT
2021-01-22,CGT 
2021-01-23,CGT 
2021-01-25,CGT 
2021-01-26,CGT 
2021-01-27,CGT 
2021-01-28,CGT
```

> If you specify '2021-01-23' you expect to get:

```
|    input    |
--------------- 
2021-01-21,CGT
2021-01-22,CGT 
2021-01-25,CGT 
2021-01-26,CGT 
2021-01-27,CGT 
2021-01-28,CGT
```

You did not specify the database you are using.  However, the concept should be similar regardless of the database platform.

```
SELECT *
FROM sample
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(input,',',1) <> '2021-01-22'
```

[MySQL]

> In [DB2], Given that you wish to pass in the input string and extract
> the date, do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM sample
WHERE SUBSTRING(input,1, (LOCATE(',',input) - 1)) <> '2021-01-22'
```

Comment: I am performing this query in DB2. My query is like :- select column_name from table where column_name LIKE ‘“+input+”’;   I have to pass the input value as specified and get the records which contain CGT but other than the date mentioned in the input value.

Comment: @Aamirkhan, I updated my response to show the corresponding query in DB2.  If this is not what you need, please give an example of tabular data before and afterward and an example of the SQL query you attempted.